# How to make carousel display more than one slide?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

Carousel I have only displays one post at a time. Ideally, I would like to use PHP to display a mysql query. What's wrong from the `JS` and `HTMl` code?
When I see the Fiddle the demo, it works great until I put it in my website. At first glance is there something wrong.

What happens is the elements of slides just show up as one slide all the way to the left.

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
   <?php
      $count_row = 0;
      while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
          if ($count_row == 0 ){
              ?>
   <div class="item active">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
         <a href="#1"><img src="post_image/Snip20161219_9.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <?php
      $count_row = $count_row + 1;

      } else if (count_row == 2) {
      $count_row = $count_row + 1; ?>
   <div class="item active">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
         <a href="#1"><img src="post_image/Snip20161219_9.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <?php
      $count_row = $count_row+1;
      } else if (count_row == 1) {  ?>
   <div class="item active">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
         <a href="#1"><img src="post_image/Snip20161219_9.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <?php
      $count_row = $count_row+1;

      } else { ?>
   <div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
         <a href="#1"><img src="post_image/Snip20161219_9.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <?php
      $count_row = $count_row + 1;

      }
      ?>
   <?php };?>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
          // Instantiate the Bootstrap carousel
          $('.multi-item-carousel').carousel({
            interval: false
          });

          // for every slide in carousel, copy the next slide's item in the slide.
          // Do the same for the next, next item.
          $('.carousel .item').each(function() {
                var next = $(this).next();
                if (!next.length) {
                  next = $(this).siblings(':first');
                }
                next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

                if (next.next().length > 0) {
                  next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
                } else {
                  $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
                }
```

Comment: Consider formatting your code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480041/css3-transform-animation-doesnt-work-in-ie-11-for-a-dynamically-created-element

Comment: `<div class="carousel-inner">
<?php if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){ while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?>
   <div class="item active">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
         <a href="#1"><img src="post_image/Snip20161219_9.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
      </div>
   </div>
<?php }}else{echo "No column found";}?>
</div>`

Comment: two problems:- since you are using only `<img src="post_image/Snip20161219_9.png"` so that may lead to confusion. Also code is not properly written'

Comment: The code is formatted. The problem was with three active and then it won't go to next.